# How to prove that this set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

i want to prove that $$A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2, x^2+y^2\leq1\}$$ is bounded

my idea is to prove that $diam(A)<\infty$

$$
diam(A)=\sup_{X,Y\in A} d_2(X,Y)=\sup_{X,Y\in A} \sqrt{(x_0-y_0)^2+(x_1-y_1)^2}
$$

how to do with $-2(x_0y_0+x_1y_1)$

Thank you

Comment: What is your definition of bounded set?

Comment: the diametr is finite

Comment: I think it's pretty much obvious that this set is bounded. The Euclidean norm of a vector in $A$ can't be bigger than $1$. So unless you use a different definition for a bounded set I don't see a reason to work with $diam(A)$.

Comment: i need an other prove using diameter @Mark

Comment: You can equivalently define A to be $ A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : d_2(x, 0) \leq 1\} $. This definition yields that $ diam(A) \leq 2 $ by the triangle inequality.

Comment: i don't understand why you replace y by 0 ? it is not the same set @user571438

Comment: @Poline Sandra In my comment x is a vector in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $ and 0 is the origin, so they are the same set.

Comment: oh tjen why 2 we just find 1@user571438

Comment: @Poline Sandra the diameter of the set is not 1. In fact, you can show that it's exactly two. To witness this, note that the points x = (-1, 0) and y = (1, 0) are in A. Also d(x, y) = 2. I'll go through the proof to make it more clear. Let x, y in A. Then d(x, y) <= d(x, 0) + d(0, y) by the triangle inequality. d(x, 0) + d(0, y) = d(x, 0) + d(y, 0). As x and y are in A, by the characterization of A I wrote in my first comment, d(x, 0) <= 1 and d(y, 0) <= 1. Thus, d(x, y) <= d(x, 0) + d(y, 0) <= 2. As x and y were arbitrary, diam(A) <= 2.

Answer (score 1):

If $(x,y),(x',y')\in A$ then: $$d((x,y),(x',y'))\leq d((x,y),(0,0))+d((0,0),(x',y'))\leq 1+1=2$$

So: $$\text{diam}(A)=\sup\{d((x,y),(x',y'))\mid (x,y),(x',y')\in A\}\leq2$$

---

If possible then put the definition based on "diameter" aside.

A set $B\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is by definition bounded if $B\subseteq B((0,0),r)$ for some $r<\infty$.

That works much more handy and is equivalent with the definition based on diameter.

Here $B((0,0),r)$ is an open ball with $(0,0)$ as center and $r$ as radius.

Answer (score 0):

We have $(x,y)\in A\iff \|(x,y)\|\le 1$, where $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the euclidean norm. Hence $A$ is trivially bounded. Recall that a set $D$ is bounded in a normed space iff there exists $M>0$ s.t. $\|x\|\le M$ for any $x\in D$.

Comment: i need an other proof with the diameter

Comment: please do you have an idea with the diameter?

Comment: In the metric space the diameter of the ball is not greater than twice the radius. This is enough for your proof. Nevertheless, in the euclidean metric the diameter is precisely twice the radius.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y), (x',y') \in A$.

By triangle inequality $d((x,y),(x',y') \le d((x,y),(0,0)) + d((x',y'),(0,0))=$

$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2} \le$

$\sqrt 1 + \sqrt 1 = 2$.

So $diam(A) \le 2$.

.....

Or to continue what you started:

$diam(A)=\sup_{X,Y\in A} d_2(X,Y)=\sup_{X,Y\in A} \sqrt{(x_0-y_0)^2+(x_1-y_1)^2}$

$= \sqrt {x_0^2 - 2x_0y_0 + y_0^2 + x_1^2 - 2x_1y_1 + y_1^2} \le$

$\sqrt {x_0^2 + 2|x_0y_0| + y_0^2 + x_1^2 + 2|x_1y_1| + y_1^2} \le$

$\sqrt {(|x_0| + |y_0|)^2 + (|x_1| + |y_1|)^2}$.

Note:  If $(a,b) \in A$ then $|a| = \sqrt {a^2} \le \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \le \sqrt 1 =1$ so

$\sqrt {(|x_0| + |y_0|)^2 + (|x_1| + |y_1|)^2}\le \sqrt { (1+ 1)^2+(1+1)^2} =\sqrt 3 = 2\sqrt 2$

Not as efficient but it'll get you there.